# Add values to a table cell using C#

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, insert

I want to add multiple values to a table cell separated by commas, the table I got is
Id ,Name , Type . I want to add multiple names in the name column, so the row will be something like:

```
ID  Name                              Type
1   Peter, Jas , Roden , Karen        Class A
```

I have done simple insertion which is:

```
[WebMethod]
public static string Insertion(string Name)  
{
    //List<string> result = new List<string>();
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Data Source=XXX;Initial Catalog=XXX;User ID=sa;Password=XXXXX");
    {
         string query = "Insert into TestTable values @Name";

        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, con);
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@Name", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = Name;
        {
            con.Open();
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

            //test();
            con.Close();
            return "True";

        }
    }
}
```

Can any one guide me on how to add multiple names which should be separated by commas, also I need to make sure there is no duplication of names.

Comment: getting any exception?

Comment: Is it you design this table structure? Can you change table structure?

Comment: yeh i have design it , we can modify it if we want, no i m not getting any exception , coz i m using insert so its adding another row , i want to update the same row

Answer (score 1):

> Can any one guide me on how to add multiple names which should be separated by commas

You need to use parameterized queries. It will also help you inb avoiding sql injection attacks.

like

```
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@name",name);
```

> also i need to make sure there is no duplication of names

Something like this should work for you

```
string name = "a,b,c,d,a,b,c,d";
HashSet<string> h = new HashSet<string>(name.Split(','));
string distinctNames = string.Join(",", h);
```

Comment: actually i want to save all the names within the name cell , then later on i can get all the names by removing the comas and populate the dropdownlist

Comment: does your string name is something like my example above? if so then above answer should do the trick for you

Comment: nope its the user who enter the name in the textbox , then he/she press the add button , in this way names are added to the row, so actuqlly i need to update and add names to that row each time when a different user eneter his/her name

Comment: then you need to keep the logic in stored procedure and decide in there where the record needs to be added.

Answer (score 1):

you can send parameter value as `"Peter, Jas , Roden , Karen"` then it will insert that text in to given record.

but if you have array or List of names to be added, you can easily create the insert string as below

```
var names = string.Join("," ,namesArray.Distinct());
```

now you can call the service method using above generated names string

Comment: well this can be done as , there are different users from different machines adding there names

Comment: you don't have column to check from which user this record inserted!

Comment: i dont need to check , the system should just add the names to the name column separated by commas , just checking the name is not a duplicate

Comment: i am still confused , should i used an update statement to add names ?

Comment: But This is not the way to Do this. You better put one name per each record. Depending on data type you set for name column there are limitations on maximum data you can add to one cell. when your application expand how you going to handle that?

Comment: well the name list wont exceed , the maximum it will have is 15 names